# Is it good practise to expose the address of a struct property?

Tags: objective-c

Assume I have an object with a property which is a c struct (say for backward compatibility with existing software)

typedef struct {
    ...
} image;

@property (assign) image img;

Assume now that that some function func( image *img ) needs the address of img.

I have two alternatives (that I can see):

1) write a getter method in the class which returns the *address* of img
and pass this address to func()

2) make a copy of the struct as in
image img0 = object.img;
func( &img0 );

Now (1) is faster, while (2) is "safer" meaning that func won't be able to mess up object data.
Is there a "standard" way of doing this, or it's basically up to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically up to you.

Note that in (2), if `func()` is supposed to modify the struct, those modifications won't affect `object.img` unless you assign the modified struct back to that property.

If `func()` *doesn't* modify the struct, you can declare it to take a const pointer and you can make a method which returns a const pointer. That doesn't leave you open to encapsulation violations. Still, it seems like a code smell to me.

A different approach would be to make a method which accepts a block to operate on the struct. The block would take a (non-const) pointer to the struct as a parameter. The block could modify the struct through that pointer. However, as part of the design contract, it must not save that pointer for use after the block completes. This allows the object to give temporary direct access to the struct in a way which doesn't violate encapsulation. The object always has a way to be aware of the modifications which are made, because the client has to invoke a method on it.

For absolute safety against a caller saving the pointer to the struct, the method could make a temporary copy, pass the pointer to the copy to the block, validate the struct contents after the block returns if necessary, and, if it's valid, assign it back to its internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to declare and access struct in objective-c

```
typedef struct Books
{
   NSString *title;
   NSString *author;
   NSString *subject;
   int   book_id;
}BookStructure;

//Now create property of BOOK1
@property(assign)BookStructure BookObj;
//Now setting value in structure variavble
int main( )
{

   self.BookObj.title = @"Objective-C Programming";
return 0;
}
```

Refer this for more details [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_structures.htm):-

Comment: Nothing in that "tutorial" addresses structs as properties of objects.